# How to install ibus-avro in 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04, ibus, ibus-avro

I am trying to install ibus-avro using following commands.

```
wget "https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases/download/v2.0/avro_2.0-1_all.deb"


sudo apt-get install -fy

sudo dpkg -i avro_2.0-1_all.deb
```

But it's not working , it keep me showing dependency errors. 
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `dpkg -i /deb/file` followed by `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: Have tried that too but didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Run these commands from the terminal, its may help:

```
$ wget "https://github.com/maateen/avro/releases/download/v2.0/avro_2.0-1_all.deb"
$ sudo dpkg -i --force-depends avro_2.0-1_all.deb
$ ibus restart
```

Now go to **`System Settings -> Keyboard -> Text Entry`**. Search and add Avro Phonetic as input source.